# What happens when a user is suspended from a meta site?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, account-suspension, per-site-meta

In particular:

- Can the suspended user still access the main site normally?
- Can the suspended user still access chat normally?

(This question doesn't really apply to MSO, as this is not a proper per-site meta.)

Comment: If you have further questions about this, please ask them in the next 23 hours. Yes, I've done _science!_

Comment: It still works for Meta since you can be boxed here, but run amok on other sites

Comment: @random Well a MSO ban _does_ block you from chat.MSO I would assume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is outdated, we can no longer suspend from just meta. All suspensions have to be carried out from main (the mod  message/suspend option is greyed out on meta).

When a user is suspended on main, the suspension carries over to meta.

MSO is an exception, as always.

Answer (score 7):

1. The user is effectively suspended from meta.
2. The user is not suspended from the site.
3. The user is not suspended from the chat. Refreshing his profile also doesn't make the meta ban carry over to his chat user account.

This makes meta suspensions useful if you have a user that's just vandalizing meta with short-lived whinings without creating (too much) trouble otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, but is this the same with _mso_, or just the 2.0 sites? I'm oddly reluctant to suspend myself in the name of science. I thought a suspension on MSO also kicked a user out of chat?

Comment: @TimPost Chat.MSO? Most likely. Chat.SE? [Not necessarily.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3154/evan-carroll)

Comment: I wonder which user could possibly be vandalizing your Meta.  Hehe.